# Missing OpenCL.so file / No GPU found

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am having trouble trying to get my graphic card to be recognised, not just recognised, but for it being able make use of it's OpenCL/GL drivers for use in Gaming mostly and BitCoin mining.

I have ASUS N56Vz running Linux Mint 16(petra) (Cinnamon), wasn't too sure if it be suitable to post about Linux Mint here, but Linux Mint and Ubuntu aren't all that too different from each other, issue happens on either systems.

that one annoying problem I can't seem to find the answer to after searching the Internet, BitCoin miner is unable to find the GPU or CPU built-in to the system. Giving me that `No GPU detected` and the `Could not find libOpenCL.so.*`

`Linux ASUS 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Now before coming posting my question here I did read over this topic here » [Open cl in intel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412009/open-cl-in-intel/440195#440195), I followed that and got Intel CPU/GPU to be detected properly in Bitminter, just not my secondary built-in graphics card which is NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M.

> lspci | grep VGA
>
> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
>
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 630M] (rev ff)

they seem to be detected correctly by the system, but they don't recognise when it comes to CPU/GPU computing for Bitminter for BitCoin mining. Also I do notice in playing games too that the graphics drivers aren't working as it should be. For some games they work just fine, but for some other games I get black textured graphics, or even white textured graphics, really bit confused why it says they are being detected yet they don't function as they should be doing normally for other stuff.

after running a test here's my output for Intel HD Graphics using the Beignet to test for the OpenCL driver.

```
Number of available platforms: 1
Platform names:
    [0] Experiment Intel Gen OCL Driver [Selected]
Number of devices available for each type:
    CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU: 0
    CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU: 1
    CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR: 0

*** Detailed information for each device ***

CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU[0]
    CL_DEVICE_NAME: Intel HD Graphics Family
    CL_DEVICE_AVAILABLE: 1
    CL_DEVICE_VENDOR: Intel
    CL_DEVICE_PROFILE: FULL_PROFILE
    CL_DEVICE_VERSION: OpenCL 1.1
    CL_DRIVER_VERSION: 0.2
    CL_DEVICE_OPENCL_C_VERSION: OpenCL C 1.1
    CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS: 128
    CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY: 1000
    CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE: 512
    CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS: 32
    CL_DEVICE_MEM_BASE_ADDR_ALIGN: 32
    CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE: 134217728
    CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE: 4
    CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE: 65536
    CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_CACHE_SIZE: 8192
    CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_CACHELINE_SIZE: 128
    CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE: 65536
    CL_DEVICE_PROFILING_TIMER_RESOLUTION: 80
    CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_SUPPORT: 1
    CL_DEVICE_ERROR_CORRECTION_SUPPORT: 0
    CL_DEVICE_HOST_UNIFIED_MEMORY: 0
    CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS: cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics     cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics     cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_icd     cl_khr_gl_sharing
    CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_INT: 16
    CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_LONG: 16
    CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_FLOAT: 16
    CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_DOUBLE: 0
    CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_INT: 16
    CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_LONG: 16
    CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_FLOAT: 16
    CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_DOUBLE: 16
```

I have latest Nvidia drivers installed, or what I think is the latest that can be fetched from the repository `nvidia-319-updates` I have checked with my model of Intel CPU and NVIDIA card that they **are** OpenCL/GL compatible. NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M has CUDA support built in according to NVIDIA's driver homepage.

I know graphics support for NVIDIA is a little sketchy and a bit unstable as they are for Linux still currently, even after installing NVIDIA's own official driver releases. My ASUS laptop is capable of Hybrid graphics switching, and as far as I've been able to search up on Google, that it is possible to do that on Linux, but involves a bit of tweaking and such so it can switch between Intel HD Graphics/Nvidia at any time without having to reboot.

```
inxi -Gx
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0 
           Card-2: NVIDIA GF108M [GeForce GT 630M] bus-ID: 01:00.0 
           X.Org: 1.14.5 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1366x768@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Mobile GLX Version: 1.4 (3.0 Mesa 9.2.1) Direct Rendering: No
```

as seen there it says `fbdev` and `vesa` is unloaded, I dunno if this is the cause why it doesn't want to load properly, I should probably look at trying to enable them somehow.

Back to the main issue, the issue being the `libOpenCL.so` file being missing on the system, which is suppose to be inside `/usr/lib/` or something like that,  just running `nvidia-detector` returns `none` to the terminal screen. I have `bumblebee-nvidia` installed too but this doesn't seem to make it work either as well as CUDA related libs.

I'm running around a bit lost trying to find an answer to getting this to work and not turning up much results besides Googling certain specific errors that pop-up.

Comment: Have you verified you completed all the steps listed here: http://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2011-06-24/install-opencl-on-debianubuntu-orderly/

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues (but not the same,) and I installed `boinc-amd-opencl` (I used synaptic package manager to find it, but `apt-get` should work,) then I rebooted and it now detects my video card.

Hope this helps.