# Installation of Intel OpenCL

Tags: intel, opencl

Since I have a Intel HD 5000 and would like for Blender to work a little faster, I am trying to get Intel's OpenCL support to work on my Ubuntu 14.04. I installed `clinfo`, `ocl-icd-libopencl1` and the latest OpenCL SDK from Intel (although, they do not seem to provide deb packages anymore, so "installing").

Now with the OpenCL SDK "installed" I get the following in `/etc/OpenCL/vendors/`:

```
intel64.icd -> /etc/alternatives/opencl-intel-runtime-icd
```

and in `/etc/alternatives/`:

```
opencl-intel-runtime-icd -> /opt/intel/intel-opencl-1.2-4.6.0.92/opencl-1.2-4.6.0.92/etc/intel64.icd
opencl-libOpenCL.so      -> /opt/intel/intel-opencl-1.2-4.6.0.92/opencl-1.2-4.6.0.92/lib64/libOpenCL.so
```

All symlinks seem to be set up correctly.

The content of `intel64.icd` then is:

```
/opt/intel/intel-opencl-1.2-4.6.0.92/opencl-1.2-4.6.0.92/lib64/libintelocl.so
```

which also exists.

Now, when I call `clinfo` I get:

```
E: -1
```

and Blender also does not seem to recognize OpenCL.

I am out of ideas right now, is there anything else to test or did I miss a setup step?

**EDIT:**

Now I executed [this](https://gist.github.com/rmcgibbo/6314452#checking-your-opencl-installation) and got the following:

```
clDeviceQuery Starting...

2 OpenCL Platforms found

 CL_PLATFORM_NAME:  Experiment Intel Gen OCL Driver
 CL_PLATFORM_VERSION:   OpenCL 1.1 beignet 0.3
OpenCL Device Info:

 No devices found supporting OpenCL (return code -1)

clDeviceQuery, Platform Name = Experiment Intel Gen OCL Driver, Platform Version = OpenCL 1.1 beignet 0.3, NumDevs = 0
 CL_PLATFORM_NAME:  Intel(R) OpenCL
 CL_PLATFORM_VERSION:   OpenCL 1.2 LINUX
OpenCL Device Info:

 1 devices found supporting OpenCL on: Intel(R) OpenCL

 ----------------------------------
 Device Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4650U CPU @ 1.70GHz
 ---------------------------------
  CL_DEVICE_NAME:           Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4650U CPU @ 1.70GHz
  CL_DEVICE_VENDOR:             Intel(R) Corporation
  CL_DRIVER_VERSION:            1.2.0.92
  CL_DEVICE_TYPE:           CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
  CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS:      4
  CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS:   3
  CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES:    8192 / 8192 / 8192 
  CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE:    8192
  CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY:    1700 MHz
  CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS:       64
  CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE:     1877 MByte
  CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE:        7509 MByte
  CL_DEVICE_ERROR_CORRECTION_SUPPORT:   no
  CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_TYPE:     global
  CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE:     32 KByte
  CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE:   128 KByte
  CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_PROPERTIES:       CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE
  CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_PROPERTIES:       CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE
  CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_SUPPORT:      1
  CL_DEVICE_MAX_READ_IMAGE_ARGS:    480
  CL_DEVICE_MAX_WRITE_IMAGE_ARGS:   480

  CL_DEVICE_IMAGE <dim>         2D_MAX_WIDTH     16384
                    2D_MAX_HEIGHT    16384
                    3D_MAX_WIDTH     2048
                    3D_MAX_HEIGHT    2048
                    3D_MAX_DEPTH     2048
  CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_<t>  CHAR 1, SHORT 1, INT 1, FLOAT 1, DOUBLE 1


clDeviceQuery, Platform Name = Experiment Intel Gen OCL Driver, Platform Version = OpenCL 1.1 beignet 0.3, NumDevs = 0
Intel(R) OpenCL, Platform Version = OpenCL 1.2 LINUX, NumDevs = 1, Device = Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4650U CPU @ 1.70GHz

System Info: 

 Local Time/Date =  00:01:09, 11/05/2014
 CPU Name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4650U CPU @ 1.70GHz 
 # of CPU processors: 4
```

Comment: Intel doesn't provide much in the way of free linux support.  Here is what worked for me - at least a little - http://askubuntu.com/questions/412009/open-cl-in-intel/440195#440195