# Intel OpenCL on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics, opencl

I was trying to intall Intel OpenCL Runtime 15.1 for Ubuntu. I have a Xeon E3 Haswell.

Now, release notes clearly state 14.04 *is supported*: https://software.intel.com/file/448151/download , and installation instructions are pretty clear.

BUT, when I try to download the runtime from the official download page

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers#ubuntu64

it downloads Intel Code Builder for Ubuntu, which supports 12.04 only.

How can I get runtime 15.1 installed on my Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/545763/installation-of-intel-opencl

Answer (score -1):

`apt-cache search opencl` returns the following:

```
opencl-1.2-intel-cpu - OpenCL™ runtime for Intel® CPU device
opencl-1.2-devel - Set of OpenCL™ C header files
opencl-1.2-intel-devel - Intel tools for OpenCL™ application's development
opencl-1.2-base - OpenCL™ installable client driver loader
```

If they don't work follow the instructions here:

[Ubuntu version of OpenCL - comment](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/390630#comment-1832283)